# Azure SQL - is it possible to assign CREATE PROCEDURE permission for the master database?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am trying to add a stored procedure to the master database (I deliberately am trying this for the master db) on Azure SQL. Is this possible? I suspect the answer is "no", but I'd like to see some confirming documentation on it if that is the case.

What I've tried so far:

Here's the procedure (just as a test):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.blah AS RETURN 0;
```

I've tried the above using the admin login, and it failed:

```
Msg 262, Level 14, State 18, Procedure blah, Line 2 [Batch Start Line 21]
CREATE PROCEDURE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

I then tried to create another login and user and then assigned them to the "dbmanager" role and tried the create procedure again - same failure.

Answer (score 0):

Not if you are using Azure DB.  Probably if you use Azure Instance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server#security

Comment: Could you quote the section that is pertaining to my issue? I looked through it and didn't see anything that looked relevant to the question.